# How to find record date within a year

Tags: sqlite, time

I am trying to find number of tickets which issues in the past year, my table looks like the following:

```
create table tickets (
  tno       int,
  fine      int,
  vdate     date,
);
```

and my current sqlite code is like:

```
 SELECT COUNT(t.tno)
  FROM tickets t
  WHERE  strftime('%Y', 'now') - strftime('%Y', t.vdate) <=1;
```

However, this queries would return the number of ticket issued in both 2018 and 2019. I would like to narrow my time range to 2018/10/11 to 2019/10/11 (today).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT count(t.no)
FROM tickets AS t
WHERE t.vdate BETWEEN date('now', '-1 year') AND CURRENT_DATE;
```

See the [documentation for date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for all the modifiers they can take, like `'-1 year'`.

This does assume your `vdate` column holds dates formatted like `YYYY-MM-DD`, which if you're already using it with `strftime()` is probably the case, but in the absence of sample data it's best to mention it.